# How do you read a file with formulas in phpspreadsheet?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I have the following code:

```
$Reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
$Reader->setReadDataOnly( true );
try {
   $spreadSheet = $Reader->load( $file );
} catch (\Exception $e) {
   echo json_encode( $e->getMessage() );
   exit;
} catch (\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Exception $e) {
   echo json_encode( $e->getMessage() );
   exit;
}

$excelSheet = $spreadSheet->getActiveSheet();
$spreadSheetAry = $excelSheet->toArray();
$maxCell = $excelSheet->getHighestRowAndColumn();
$data = $excelSheet->rangeToArray( 'A1:' . $maxCell['column'] . $maxCell['row'] );
$data = array_map( 'array_filter', $data );
$data = array_filter( $data );
```

which works fine, if it is file that contains no formulas. But if I try to read a file that contains formulas, I get the following error:
**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 67108872 bytes) in /var/www/html/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Cell/Coordinate.php on line 395**

My question is, how can I get phpspreadsheet to either ignore or calculate the formulas inside the file? The error occurs in **$Reader->load( $file );** while trying to read it, so i'm not able to get back any data from the file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you extend PHP memory_limit in php.ini to see if the issue still raised?

Comment: I just read the source of Coordinate.php where the exception accrues and I don't think this is anything to do with formulas. https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Cell/Coordinate.php#L395

Comment: @ali i have already tried with the memory_limit in php.ini. It didn't change anything. Somehow this only occurs when i have a file with formulas, i tried with a different file and it worked like it should do

Answer (score 0):

```
$Reader->setReadDataOnly( true );
```

says read only the data and that you can't use the calculation more information see [here.](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/calculation-engine/)

Remove above line or set it to false

Comment: that didn't help either